# Overloading constructor of child class

Tags: java, inheritance, this, super

Say for example I have a `Circle` class:

```
static final double DEFAULT_RADIUS = 1.0;

Circle(Point centre, double radius) {
    this.centre = centre;
    this.radius = radius;
}

Circle(Point centre) {
    this(centre, Circle.DEFAULT_RADIUS);
}

// ...
```

Then in `ColoredCircle`, a child class of `Circle`:

```
ColoredCircle(Point centre, Color color, double radius) {
    super(centre, radius);
    this.color = color;
}

ColoredCircle(Point centre, Color color) {
    // ???
}
```

What should go in for the second constructor of `ColoredCircle`?

- `this(centre, color, Circle.DEFAULT_RADIUS);`
- `super(centre, Circle.DEFAULT_RADIUS); this.color = color;`

I think either would work, but which would result in "cleaner code"?

Comment: Life could be much easier without using inheritance but interfaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your examples are a bit redundant, since `Circle` already has a constructor that sets the radius to the default value.

I'd suggest you use it, and just make your constructor like so:

```
super(centre);
this.color = color;
```